# Does the upper part of kitchen range hood detach?

Tags: chimney

In summer my kitchen gets very hot during cooking and it becomes very sweaty. I want to install a range hood in my kitchen. But the issue is that, I have only 120 cms free above my cook top. Above that I have water tank.

I am confused which range hood should I buy which can be fit in this space of 120 cms. There are various kinds of range hoods. I am referring to this [manual](http://www.elicaindia.com/pdfFile/Brochure.pdf).

**Range hood type 1**
Consider this one:

[image]

If we consider 65cm free height between cook top and range hood, it will consume full 65+50=115 cm. Then how can I take out duct pipe out of it. Can I cut some part of of 50cm (500 mm in image) top part in order to take out duct pipe? Or I cannot since that part house some type of machinery?

**Range hood type 2**
Consider this one:
[image]

This seems to be of total height 448 mm = 45cm approx. If I consider 45cm of free space (as recommended by manual), then it will consume 45+45=90 cm. Here I dont have any part to cut so as to fit the duct pipe. Duct pipe has to strictly start from 110cm.

**Range hood type 3**
Consider this one:
[image]

This has small height, so that they can be fully fitted in space available. But these types of range hoods come with less suction capacity and width.

Will it work (i.e. I will be able to fit it with pipe in 120cm) if I buy any of first two types?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, your best source for this kind of question is the manufacturer(s), as they're the ones who actually know the design of these hoods.

Comment: But users also get to have a look at those products. So can't they also have some idea? In fact for almost all products, its users who share reviews online, which help us take our decisions. And its users who usually write xyz buying guides...

Comment: Well, hopefully you're right and get a good answer.

Comment: Post a picture of the area you want to install this range hood, as well as the water tank above.